# How to export text from R into one cell in Excel

Tags: r, text, export-to-csv, export-to-excel

I have 3205 observations in my dataset. Each observation contains several paragraphs worth of text and looks something like this:

| BRIEF_ID | STATE | BRIEF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01999110036250 | ALABAMA | paragraphs of text here... |

My goal is to export this dataset into Excel/csv so that it looks exactly like it does in R. So far I've tried different variations of this:

```
write.table(MyData, file="MyData.csv", sep=",")
```

Unfortunately, when I use this syntax, it exports into Excel/csv in a very weird way, splitting the paragraphs of text into multiple columns and multiple rows. For example

| BRIEF_ID | STATE | BRIEF |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01999110036250 | ALABAMA | paragraphs | text |
| of |  |  |  |
| here... |  |  |  |

Any idea how I can keep the paragraphs of text together in one cell?

*********UPDATED TEXT/NOTEPAD EXAMPLE FOR 1 OBSERVATION**********

41,' ' 0499970019131,ARIZONA,"GOOD AFTERNOON EVERYONE., THANK YOU FOR BEING HERE TODAY., AND I WANT TO UPDATE YOU ON WHERE ARIZONA
IS IN ITS CURRENT SITUATION, WHERE OUR NUMBERS, ARE, AND THE ACTION STEPS WE INTEND TO TAKE
GOING FORWARD., I WANT TO BEGIN BY JUST AGAIN SAYING THANK
YOU TO ALL OF OUR NURSES, DOCTORS, EMERGENCY, MEDICAL RESPONDERS, AND HEALTHCARE WORKERS,
T",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
DAY THAT WE ARE DEFINITELY,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the raw CSV, but have you tried to use a different separator like pipes "|" My guess is that somewhere in the multiple paragraphs there are commas that are confusing Excel when it tries to separate. Suggest posting a snap of the raw CSV (right click open in notepad).

Comment: Without sample data, this is unfortunately just conjecture. I just ran a simple test with `write.table(data.frame(id=1,state="AL",brief="long\nmultiline,commas\neven,more"), "quux.csv", sep = ",")` and opened it in excel with exactly one row, where the third cell had multiple lines. I suggest you need to work on a reproducible example, the current state of your question is not there.

Comment: @alexrai93 Fair point. I'll include an text/notepad file example for one observation in the above description now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, supposing you have a dataframe `data` in memory, then:

```r
# run install.packages("writexl") to install it 
writexl::write_xlsx(data, "my_data.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this suggestion! Unfortunately it looks like the data in each cell is too large. I received this error: Error: Error in libxlsxwriter: 'String exceeds Excel's limit of 32,767 characters.'

Comment: hmm... Now that I think about it, could it be possible that it is splitting those cells whereby the paragraphs excel the character limit per cell? If so, might you know a way to manage that?

Comment: If you reeeeally want it you could do something like ``data %>% dplyr::mutate(brief = list(stringr::str_split_fixed(brief, n = allowed_amount_of_characters))) %>% tidyr::unnest(brief) %>% writexl::write_xlsx("my_data.csv")``

Comment: is "allowed_amount_of_characters" supposed to be written as is, or should I give it a value? I ask because I left it as written and received this error: Error in dplyr::mutate(., BRIEF = list(stringr::str_split_fixed(BRIEF, : 

Caused by error in `str_split()`:
! object 'allowed_amount_of_characters' not found

Comment: That error simply means that no object called `allowed_amount_of_characters` was defined. You're supposed to define it with a number value you deem appropriate or hardcode the value inplace, whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

write_xlsx will probably help but from the CSV posted I think the issue is parsing. The csv sample gets imported mostly intact in Excel 365 in that the main paragraph is in a single cell on my machine so it must be some CSV / local setting on your end while importing.

Working with CSV for large amounts of unstructured text that has commas can cause a lot of strange issues. I would change the separator to | or something even less commonly used by humans. Then import it using Excel Power Query by opening a blank workbook and selecting "Get Data -> Text/CSV" under the data tab and telling it what delimiter you used. You can also specify the csv format in the power query import although excel takes a good guess.

Also it may be stating the obvious but those rows of ,,,,,, will translate into blank columns, I am assuming that is intended if not then there may be an issue with how the data is structured for export.